# Add two different SQL Count Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have two separate Count queries. I want to divide the two queries and multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

The two Queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
 (
     SELECT * FROM admin WHERE principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM admin where deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
) as Count1

SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 FROM admin as Count2
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT(
         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
                  (
                       SELECT * FROM admin WHERE principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
                       UNION
                       SELECT * FROM admin where deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
                   )
             /

                  (
                       SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 FROM admin as Count2
                  )
       )
```

But i get syntax errors which I am unable to debug correctly. Which is the correct way of going about this?

It should divide Count1 and Count2 then multiply by 100 and display it as such:

```
37%
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008 why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: Are there any rows where both `principal` and `deputy_principal` contain `"Mrs"`, did you want to count those twice?

Comment: You might find that counting on the PK is marginally faster than counting on everything.

Comment: Also you may find this [Windowing Functions tutorial useful](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-window-functions-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM admin WHERE principal LIKE '%Mrs%' 
         OR deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%') / 
    (SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) * 2 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM admin)) * 100
```

**UDPATE: Comparison vs original approach with dummy data....**

```
DECLARE @admin TABLE(Id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1), principal VARCHAR(50), 
    deputy_principal VARCHAR(50))
INSERT @admin (principal, deputy_principal)
VALUES ('Mr Person 1', 'Mr Person 2'),
        ('Mrs Person 3', 'Mr Person 4'),
        ('Mr Person 5', 'Mrs Person 6'),
        ('Mrs Person 7', 'Mrs Person 8')

-- Original attempted way (syntax corrected)        
SELECT ((
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    FROM
    (
       SELECT * FROM @admin WHERE principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM @admin where deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
   ) x)
   /
   (SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) * 2 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM @admin)) * 100

-- Shortened query      
SELECT
((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM @admin WHERE principal LIKE '%Mrs%' 
     OR deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%') / 
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) * 2 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM @admin)) * 100
```

Both output the same result: 37.5 in this example

Comment: that could give a different result, but this may be the result the OP actually wants.

Comment: This gives me an answer of Zero yet when I execute the queries differently they all have values

Comment: @WilliamTheDev I've updated my answer, needed to conver the counts to decimals as they were integers (hence 0 output)

Comment: @Jodrell No, it will give the same result. See comparison update

Comment: @WilliamTheDev as far as I understand, you want 50 % here with the posted testdata, is that correct ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk ...yes, I want a percentage sign after the result. Like so {37.5%}

Comment: @WilliamTheDev that is not what i am asking. I want to know which percent you expect with the data in this example- 37.5 or 50 ?

Comment: I am using an amount and more distributed data than AdaTheDev but you should get 37.5 if you use AdaTheDev's query and data ...I tested it manually and it is correct.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev that contradict your own example. In your example these data should return 50 % because there is a total of 4 mrs in 4*2 rows (don't forget to mark an answer)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like below using `CASE Expression` and `SUM() Function`:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN principal LIKE '%Mrs%' OR 
                 deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%' THEN 100.0 END) / SUM(2) Pecentage
FROM admin
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d132d/18)** using @AdaTheDev 's data

Comment: I like this answer. Short and concise. How come you don't have to CAST on yours? I'm guessing it's because multiplying by a float value 100.0 SQL server implicitly converts it to DECIMAL...right?

Comment: Yes, if you need to limit number of decimals please wrap the results with `ROUND()` function

Comment: But, this won't double count rows where both columns contain '%Mrs%', like the OPs example. I grant this may actually be desirable.

Comment: @Jodrell, yes I agree and thanks. I missed that. May be we can handle it adding another branch to the CASE expression like `principal LIKE '%Mrs%' AND deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%' THEN 2`.

Comment: I was originally thinking two `SUM`s (as in my answer) but your extra case idea could likely be more efficient.

Comment: @Jodrell. Actually, looking at the original query again, OP is using `UNION` not `UNION ALL`. So, record won't be duplicated even if both columns contain `%Mrs%` and the resulting record count still be 1. Please correct me if wrong, my head starts to spin a bit now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all in one pass like this, **[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/098b2/21)**

```
 SELECT
    CONVERT(
        VARCHAR(10),
        (
            CONVERT(Real, SUM(Mrs))
        /
            CONVERT(Real, COUNT(*))
        ) * 100
    ) + '%'
    [DoubledUpMrsPercentage]
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN [principal] LIKE '%Mrs%' OR
                [deputy_principal] LIKE '%Mrs%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END Mrs
    FROM
        [admin]
      ) Flags;
```

Comment: Jodrell, its probably been lost in the conversion but the final answer is off by about 4.7% from the actual answer. Should've probably cast as DECIMAL instead.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev, I've amended, I think this is one of those situations where floating point numbers make sense.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev, did you really want the percentage symbol on the end?

Comment: Yes, I did. How can one output that in SQL server?

Comment: @WilliamTheDev, I've altered my answer a bit to give a more "correct" result. I'm leaving it here because you wanted a `'%'` appended to the result. However I feel Kaf's answer is superior. To give the same answer as you query leave it as is, to give a more "accurate" result substitute `SUM(2)` for `COUNT(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
cast(
  sum(case when principal LIKE '%Mrs%' then 50.0 else 0 end +
      case when deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%' then 50.0 else 0 end)
  / count(*)
 as decimal(5,2)) as percnt
from admin
```

Comment: I actually do want to multiply it by two...it was not an error. This is because that will give me the total number of administrators this is because there are 2 rows side by side - deputy and principal.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev in that case I included it again

Comment: I'm not sure why but this is giving me an answer 108% off the mark. I'm not sure what then 100.0 else 0 end parts of the query mean else I'd help debug it.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev I multiplied by 2 instead of dividing. I corrected it now

Comment: @t-clausen.dk...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Cast(a*100 as int)/b
from (
select count(*) a
from ERP_FMS_ChartOfAccount where CategoryID = 2)t1,
(
Select count(*) b
From ERP_FMS_ChartOfAccount where CategoryID = 1)t2
```

Comment: erm, whats `CategoryID`, whats `ERP_FMS_ChartOfAccount`?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @firstquerycount as integer;
declare @secondquerycount as integer;

SELECT @firstquerycount = COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE principal LIKE '%Mrs%';
SELECT @secondquerycount = COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%';
```

Now firstquerycount and secondquerycount holds the value of respective count of there respective query. You can use them as per your requirement like

```
select convert(varchar(10),(((@firstquerycount+@secondquerycount)/2)*100))+'%'
```

Note I didn't try this query - please make change as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT princi, total, (princi*100)/CAST(total AS REAL)
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN principal LIKE '%Mrs%' 
 OR deputy_principal LIKE '%Mrs%'
 THEN 1 END), COUNT(*)*2
FROM admin) AS X(princi,total)
```

Comment: You forgot to add the multiplication of COUNT * FROM admin by 2.